# C# Multiple Projects Hide Main Form only hides one time

Tags: c#, winforms

This is really a silly question. That said here are the details. I have two projects.
The main project has one form frmStart so it needs to Use Hide.
The second project is a Class Library with a form attached.
When I click the button to go to the Class Library THE FIRST TIME all is good frmStart is hidden.
When I make a SECOND CALL to go to the Class Library frmStart DOES NOT Hide ?
frmStart has KeyPreview set to True and a button to close it.
I had to create a new instance in the Class Library for frmStart not sure that was correct.
**What am I doing wrong ?**

Code for frmStart

```
    private void btnShowLib_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        SS = "HI we are from OneB";
        var form = new CLP.form1();
        form.UdpateTextBoxWith(SS);
        form.Show();
    }
```

Code in the Class Library

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        frmStart fST = new frmStart();
        fST.Show();  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong ?

In the Lib, you are creating and showing a new `frmStart` by doing this:

```cs
frmStart fST = new frmStart();
fST.Show();
```

The `fst` here is a completely different instance and not the one you think that was created and shown in your main project. In other words, you're hiding the original instance in the main project and showing a new one in the Lib project.

You can solve this by calling [`Form.ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) method to display a *modal* dialog rather than [`Form.Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) which displays a *non-modal* dialog. By doing this, you don't need to write any code in the Lib's `btnClose_Click` but the `Close();` method.

In the main project:

```cs
private void btnShowLib_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    SS = "HI we are from OneB";
    using (var form = new CLP.form1())
    {
        form.UdpateTextBoxWith(SS);
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
    Show(); // Not executed until after the form is closed.
}
```

In the Lib project:

```cs
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close();
```

---

If you have a reason to display a *non-modal* dialog, then pass the `frmStart` instance to the `Show` method then you can access it through the [`Form.Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property.

```cs
private void btnShowLib_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    SS = "HI we are from OneB";
    var form = new CLP.form1();
    form.UdpateTextBoxWith(SS);
    form.FormClosing += (_, __) => form.Owner.Show();
    form.Show(this);
}

// Lib project
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close();
```

Note, the `FormClosing` event is handled to show the owner instead of the `btnClose_Click` event because the Form can also be closed by the Form's `x` control button or keyboard keys.

---

Another *non-modal* way is to pass the `frmStart` instance to the Lib's Form through a parametrized constructor and assign it to a backing field.

```cs
namespace CLP
{
    // Find a better name...
    public class form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly Form form;

        public form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // ...
        }

        public form1 (Form frm) : this() => form = frm;

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            form.Show();
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close();

        // ...
    }
}
```

The main project:

```cs
private void btnShowLib_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    SS = "HI we are from OneB";
    var form = new CLP.form1(this);
    form.UdpateTextBoxWith(SS);
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: I knew I was wrong when I created a new instance of frmStart but it worked once ha ha on ME Thought about form.ShowDialog(); but it was not a Dialog Form WRONG the form in Class Library I guess behaves as a Dialog Form Lesson Learned Thanks a Ton my best Vector I set the Control Box to false on most of my projects it is a pain with little options to manage when it gets clicked !