# How to pass class object from a form to MainForm

Tags: c#

I am working on a recipe manager and here i need to pass the currentRecipe class object to the mainForm after adding the ingredients in the class form AddIngredients. It's a requirement in my assignment to have a currentRecipe object, and to validate this current recipe after clicking the button "add recipe". Although i don't find a way to retrieve this current recipe in my mainForm, in order to pass it to RecipeManager (an array of class objects).

```
private void validate_ingredients_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i =0; i < currentIngredients.Length; i++)
    {
        this.currentRecipe.Ingredients[i] = currentIngredients[i];
    }

    Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
    Recipe currentRecipe = this.currentRecipe;
    mainForm.passCurrentRecipe(currentRecipe);
    Close();
}
```

This is the method that closes the form ingredients and that passes the object back to the mainForm.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static int maxNumberOfElements = 200;
    RecipeManager recipeMngr = new RecipeManager(maxNumberOfElements);
    Recipe currentRecipe; 
        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeGUI();
    }

    private void InitializeGUI()
    {
        addcategory_combobox.DataSource = FoodCategories.foodCategory.GetValues(typeof(FoodCategories.foodCategory));
    }

    private void addingredients_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Recipe currentRecipe = new Recipe
        {
            Name = addrecipe_textbox.Text,
            Category = addcategory_combobox.Text,
            Description = addrecipe_textbox.Text
        };

        AddIngredients ingredientsManager = new AddIngredients(currentRecipe);
        ingredientsManager.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void addrecipe_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//can't add the recipe because this.recipe does not receive data properly
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.currentRecipe.Name);
        //recipeMngr.addRecipe(currentRecipe);
    }

    public void passCurrentRecipe(Recipe currentRecipe)
    {
        this.currentRecipe = currentRecipe;
    }
```

This is the mainForm.

I've tried this in the mainForm

```
public void passCurrentRecipe(Recipe currentRecipe)
{
    this.currentRecipe = currentRecipe
}
```

i wanted to set the value of Recipe currentRecipe to a field of mainForm with the same name so i could use it later, but the field loses the value eventually and it throws a null exception

Comment: This `Form1 mainForm = new Form1();` is wrong. It creates a **new** 
orphaned instance of type `Form1`, not the one that you see when you run your app. Replace it with `Form1 mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();`. Find better names for your objects. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75756686/14171304) Q&A for some details and alternatives.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Form.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-8.0), [Form.ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-8.0), [Handle and raise events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/).

Comment: [Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors), [Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods), and [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an event to pass Recipe data from child form to the main form.

Main form

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
// location of Recipe class
using WindowsFormsApp1.Models;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Recipe _currentRecipe;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void openChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RecipeForm recipeForm = new RecipeForm();
            recipeForm.AddRecipe += RecipeForm_AddRecipe;

            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show(recipeForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK
                    ? $"{_currentRecipe.Category}"
                    : "Nothing added");
            }
            finally
            {
                recipeForm.Dispose();
            }
        }
        private void RecipeForm_AddRecipe(Recipe recipe)
        {
            _currentRecipe = recipe;
        }
    }
}
```

Child form has two buttons, one to pass a recipe to the main form with DialogResult set to Ok, second button, DialogResult set to cancel. By setting DialogResult the form is closed, back in the main form we check DialogResult and act.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApp1.Models;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class RecipeForm : Form
    {
        public delegate void OnAddRecipe(Recipe recipe);
        public event OnAddRecipe AddRecipe;
        public RecipeForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void addIngredientsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe()
            {
                Category = "Cat1",
                Description = "TODO", 
                Name = "Recipe name"
            };
            AddRecipe?.Invoke(recipe);
        }
    }
}
```